# voice menu for incoming calls on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, voice

Is there iOS app or feature that would manage incoming calls and give unknown caller a voice menu?

For incoming calls that are not in address book
automatically answer phone call call with configured voice menu, like:

- "Hello I am voice assistant"
- "What is your name?"
  and try to speech-to-text into recoding title
- "What is birthday"
  to give some quick passthrough code

iPhone (with iOS 14) can auto answer or block calls, but I'd like to autoanswer/block more wisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS does not provide this functionality itself, and apps on the App Store are unable to do so.

Apple's [CallKit framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit) provides functionality for apps to block callers:

> Apps can create a Call Directory app extension to identify and block incoming callers by their phone number.

Apps are unable to answer calls, so none of your desired functionality is possible.

---

If your device is jailbroken, [AnsweringMachine XS](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/net.limneos.answeringmachinex/) can provide some call screening functionality, but it requires you to manually listen to the caller.

> - Call-Screening. Listen to what the remote party is saying while leaving voicemail without answering the call!

Comment: OK, not possible as there no (public) APIs yet